# Playing Rhythmbox through SSH

Tags: ssh, rhythmbox

I am trying to start Rhythmbox by remotely accessing my Ubuntu 15.04 machine through SSH. Problem is when i create a new instance of Rhythmbox and play it, it works fine. Here is how i am doing it.

```
env DISPLAY=:0 rhythmbox-client --play &
```

This creates a new instance and it starts playing. But when i pass in `--no-start` flag it does not play.

```
env DISPLAY=:0 rhythmbox-client --no-start --play &
```

It does not give any error and shows the process id but does not open it. When i try the same commands on the remote itself without the SSH it works fine.